# Are SQL Server Views processed "before" enclosing query logic

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

If I have a view, and embed the view in a query, will the view have to be processed fully before the rest of the query?

Example:

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.ExpensiveView AS
    SELECT IndexedColumn, NonIndexedColumn 
    FROM dbo.BigHairyTable 
    WHERE NonIndexedColumn BETWEEN 500000000 AND 500050000
GO

SELECT * FROM dbo.ExpensiveView
WHERE IndexedColumn BETWEEN 1000 AND 1099
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. SQL Server will "expand" the view definition and optimize it in the context of the enclosing query.

Comment: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/merrill_aldrich/archive/2010/02/11/busting-a-persistent-myth-views-are-executed-before-enclosing-queries.aspx (full disclosure - I wrote that, and this question, and this answer, because I see this misconception so often)

Comment: Provided the view definition contains no aggregates...or an ORDER BY

Comment: @Mitch: even if there are aggregates, view's definition still may be flattened out.

Comment: It's not "expanding" the view - it is passing on the predicate(s) to the view.  And it typically happens only when the view SELECT only has simple column references (no functions), and/or does not use DISTINCT/GROUP BY.  Additionally, the example does not perform functions on the columns returned from the view...